# How to convert scraped data into a list to work with

Tags: python, text, beautifulsoup

I'm working on a code which is scraping data from sites such yelp.
When I'm extracting data into text print(data.text) everything works well. But when I try to convert it into a list, I have issues.

I tried to encode it or to add str at the beginning, and I've tried to create a list to add everything inside. but it outputs 'None'.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def third_site_fc(third_site_franche_comte = requests.get("https://www.paruvendu.fr/a/utilitaire-occasion/tracteur-routier/")):

    third_soup_fc = BeautifulSoup(third_site_franche_comte.text,'html.parser')
    list = []
    for articles_third_site in third_soup_fc.find_all('div',class_='ergov3-txtannonce'):
        print(articles_third_site.text in list)

print(third_site_fc())
```

I receive this output:

```
output:False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
None
```

I was expecting a list containing all the information from the loop (not character by character). Something like

```
['abababababababab ababa ababababaab']
```

Thanks for your help and comprehension!

Comment: If `third_site_fc()` already has a print statement, why're you invoking `print(third_site_fc())` instead of just stating `third_site_fc()`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to do that?

```
def third_site_fc(third_site_franche_comte = requests.get("https://www.paruvendu.fr/a/utilitaire-occasion/tracteur-routier/")):

    third_soup_fc = BeautifulSoup(third_site_franche_comte.text,'html.parser')

    my_list = [] # Try to avoid reserved keywords
    for articles_third_site in third_soup_fc.find_all('div',class_='ergov3-txtannonce'):
        text = (articles_third_site.text
                  .replace('\n','')
                  .replace('\r',''))
        my_list.append(text)

    return my_list

print(third_site_fc())
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Exactly what i wanted to do! but now i need to find a way to get rid of the \n.

Comment: @Nakor you think that there is a raison of making -1 in my code ?

Comment: @Nakor i test my code and it's work pandasansgains  tested it to and he find that we should delete the "\n" and "\r" ; about the use of list i changed it with anther logic  i think  we shouldn't give -1 with reason of code quality  as you said because people will think that i make a wrong answer before they read it